# Firebase logging only first log

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, telegram-bot

I've been trying to work with firebase and Telegram bot API. Just as everywhere - I have to debug, but at the moment when I deploy my webhooks with logs - they are just being ignored.

Here is the code that I'm trying to invoke:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const isTelegramMessage =
    req.body
    && req.body.message
    && req.body.message.chat
    && req.body.message.chat.id
    && req.body.message.from
    && req.body.message.from.first_name

    if (isTelegramMessage) {
        const chat_id = req.body.message.chat.id
        const isUpdate = !!req.body.update_id
        const defaultSendMessageOptions = sendMessageDefaultOptionsFactory(chat_id);

        functions.logger.log(req.body);
        functions.logger.log([isUpdate]);
        functions.logger.debug([isUpdate]);
    }
```

The other code is skipped, but I'm 100% sure that it goes as a Telegram message.
At the moment, my firebase console logs something (I believe it's req.body), but not other requests.

[image: Firebase function logs]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You inspect wrong function, or your function is not updated. Try `functions.logger.log('Body', req.body);`

Comment: My function is updated, my code definitely works, and the bot changing his behavior when I change code, but logs are not passing through

Comment: @hoangdv 
Also, I've tried the code that you proposed - It didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your function in a promise?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Creating_a_Promise_around_an_old_callback_API
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise

Comment: @OliverAragon why would we use Promise here?